# Кэширование изображений при первой загрузке в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, picasso

Есть `RecyclerView` в виде сетки, сетка состоит только из изображений. При первой загрузке когда скролишь вниз изображения начинают появляться в плане анимации (placeholder) от `Picasso`, но когда доходишь до конца списка изображения все кэшируются и можно спокойно скролить вверх-вниз (так как все изображения в кэше).

Так вот как сделать прилодер, чтобы когда запускается активность с `RecyclerView`, все изображения сразу были загружены в кэш, и не было этой анимации (placeholder).

Comment: Судя по документации https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html метод fetch() реализован для этого. Попробуйте так Picasso.with(contecxt).load(url).fetch()